# How to reduce the size of the uber JAR by architecture - Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx, optimization, executable-jar

I have a problem that I hope that someone can provide a solution or an idea on how to solve it.

Here is the issue: I am creating a JavaFX application (using Eclipse IDE) that has some dependencies based on a maven pom file. The issue occurs when I try to create an uber Jar with all of the dependencies included. I am using the shade maven plugin for that matter, but when it creates the uber JAR it includes the dependencies from other architectures, like windows_x86, linux_x86, android, arm, and the list is endless.

I have tried to use the minimize option from the same shade plugin but it does not work. I only want to include the dependencies for macos_x86_64 since the application will only support MacOS for now. I have tried to do many things to troubleshoot this such as: creating the pom from zero, deleting the dependencies, running the maven dependency:analyze, setting shade minimize to true, and some more but nothing seems to work. I also analyzed the source code to make sure that I am not including some dependency that could trigger that behavior and nothing has worked.

So, is there anyone here that can provide a solution for the issue described in here? This is crazy because the super uber Jar is 1GB, but my source code is only 5MB without the dependencies and resources. I was checking how heavy the dependencies of the pom are, and they are not bigger than 200MB (considering the dependencies of the dependencies of the dependencies).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Shade seems to be the right way. How it failed? I think it might not be simple to achieve but it should be possible to filter out the binaires for other architectures. What dependencies do you have containing platform dependent code?

Comment: I use Capsule for fat jars https://dig.floatingsun.net/capsule-one-jar-to-rule-them-all-e8b845e6627d

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had that working with a config like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <excludeDefaults>false</excludeDefaults>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org/glassfish/json/JsonProviderImpl</include>
                                    <include>com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/nav/ReflectionNavigator</include>
                                    <include>com/sun/**/*</include>
                                    
                                    <include>com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/LocalDateDeserializer</include>
                                    <include>com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ext/Java7HandlersImpl</include>
                                </includes>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*.md</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/*.markdown</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/*.header</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/pom.properties</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/io.netty.versions.properties</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/*.args</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/*.so</exclude> <!-- Change this for other operating systems -->
                                    <exclude>**/*.dylib</exclude> <!-- Change this for other operating systems -->
                                    <exclude>**/*.dll</exclude> <!-- Change this for other operating systems -->
                                    <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```